# Incorrect displaing content CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
<i class="mce-ico mce-i-alignright"></i>
```

After this are `::before` pseudo:

```
.mce-i-alignright:before {
    content: "\e005";
}
```

So, it is displaying incorrect, like as square everywhere. Look at picture

[image]

Comment: Did you set the font with `font-family` so that your unicode character exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the require font loaded. the box is to indicate the character is not found.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(font_name.woff);
}
i{
font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I see in console: `Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/public/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.woff
create:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/public/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.ttf`

Comment: But it is downloading, if click above link

Comment: See my answer for the solution to this issue. @Serak Shiferaw's answer is only partially correct, in addition to specifying the source you must also specify the format or the font will not be able to be decoded properly which is what the console errors you are receiving indicate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the font those symbols require in order to display the characters correctly. You may or may not have a variety of different formats available from the font creator, you should include as many as you can in your page as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
i.mce-ico {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
}
```